# Undefined variable $categories #Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Category;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        
        return view('home', ['categories'=> $categories]);
    }
}
```

and my blade is something like this(his call "home.blade.php")

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center mb-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Categorias</h2>
                
                <hr>
                @foreach($categories as $cat)
                    <button>{{ $cat->CATEGORIA_NOME }}</button>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

the Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['CATEGORIA_NOME', 'CATEGORIA_DESC'];
    protected $table = 'CATEGORIA';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CATEGORIA_ID';
    protected $timestamp = false;

    public function categorias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'CATEGORIA_ID');
    }
}
```

but i still receiving the error:
Undefined variable $categories

I tried to using the

```
    $categories = Category::all();
    
    return view('home', ['categories'=> $categories]);
```

or

return view('home')->with('categories', $categories);

but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
return view('home', ['categories'=> Category::all()]);
```

if doesn't work try to dump your category model, see if the data is out or not

Answer (score 0):

Try using compact(), like this.

```
$categories = Category::all();

return view('home', compact('categories'));
```